# Unable to replace commas by dots in a string and vice versa

Tags: python-3.x, string, for-loop, replace, append

I am trying to replace commas in a string with dots. I have written the following code, but the output is a string with only dots and no commas. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
my_string = 't,r,y.i.n.g'
my_list= []
for x in my_string:
    if x != (',' and '.'):
        my_list.append(x)
    elif x== ",":
        my_list.append(".")
    else:
        my_list.append(",")

new_str = ''
for i in my_list:
    new_str +=i
print(new_str)
```

Comment: in the first if I think it would be if x != ',' and x != '.'

Comment: With your most recent edit, `(',' and '.')` evaluates to `'.'` so that means your first condition is `if x != '.':`.

Comment: @Axe319 - Thanks, got it now.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if x != ',' and '.':
```

Should be either

```
if x != ',' and x != '.':
```

or

```
if x not in (',', '.'):
```

The way you've written it, it's interpreting the `and '.'` to check whether `'.'` is a non-empty string, which it is, so the `and '.'` part always matches.